# Method optimization in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to optimize following method:

```
public void myLongRunningMethod()
{
LongRunningOperation1();

LongRunningOperation2();

LongRunningOperation3();

Log.Info("completion message goes here.")

}
```

LongRunningOperation1(),LongRunningOperation2() and LongRunningOperation3() are independant of each other and the order of their completion does not matter.

But the log statement should be printed only after successful completion of all these method calls.

If I take the following approach, since its using a new thread, I believe the order of completion of methods wont be guarenteed.

```
public String myMethod()
{

Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
    LongRunningOperation1();
}).start();


Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    LongRunningOperation2();
}).start();


Thread thread3 = new Thread(() -> {
    LongRunningOperation3();
}).start();

Log.Info("completion message goes here.")

}
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but you need to wait until all three tasks are finished by calling `Thread#join` on `thread1`, `thread2`, and `thread3`.

Comment: Use a `CountDownLatch` to sync when the 3 long running operations complete to print the log message and proceed.

Comment: you can make you method return a `Future` Object assume is Future1,Future2 adn Future3,before call your log method you just check Long* method finished or not like this `if(Future1.get() && Future2.get() && Future3.get())`

Answer (score 4):

As comments are mentioning, the easiest is either calling join() on each of the 3 threads: `thread1.join(); thread2.join(); thread3.join();`

Or use a `CountDownLatch` though it is a touch more involved (but maybe more conceptually 'correct'):

- `latch = new CountDownLatch(3)`
- get each thread to do `latch.countDown()` *after* completing its task.
- get the main thread to `latch.await()` - voila.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating `Thread`s manually it is much better to use `ExecutorService` `API`. Using `ExecutorService` you can submit long running operations and as result you will receive `Future` instance which will let you wait until operation will be completed.

See below example which shows the idea:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Threads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Threads().myMethod();
    }

    private String myMethod() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>(3);
        futures.add(executor.submit(this::LongRunningOperation1));
        futures.add(executor.submit(this::LongRunningOperation2));
        futures.add(executor.submit(this::LongRunningOperation3));
        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All operations are finished!");
        return "Done";
    }

    private void LongRunningOperation1() {
        sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        System.out.println("LongRunningOperation1 is finished!");
    }

    private void LongRunningOperation2() {
        sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        System.out.println("LongRunningOperation2 is finished!");
    }

    private void LongRunningOperation3() {
        sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
        System.out.println("LongRunningOperation3 is finished!");
    }

    private void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
LongRunningOperation1 is finished!
LongRunningOperation2 is finished!
LongRunningOperation3 is finished!
All operations are finished!
```